For Paladin's Ranged Reprisal, if you have multiple weapons, which Reach applies?
Paladin's Ranged Reprisal says:

You can use Retributive Strike with a ranged weapon. In addition, if the foe that triggered your reaction is within 5 feet of your reach but not in your reach, as part of your reaction you can Step to put the foe in your reach before making a melee Retributive Strike.

What if you have multiple weapons with multiple reaches?
Say the enemy is 10 feet away, and I have a longspear with a 10-foot reach. However, I want to use an unarmed strike which has a 5-foot reach. Can I still step to put the enemy in reach of my unarmed strike?

"if the foe that triggered your reaction is within 5 feet of your reach but not in your reach"
since they are in your reach that can never trigger and you wont be able to move.
it only cares about your characters reach not the weapon you "want to use"
you would have to have dropped or stowed the longspear before the triggering attack thereby lowering you reach to 5ft for it to trigger in this scenario

You're saying that what matters is "Your reach" and not "your weapon's reach", but what is the distinction between those two things?

@Strill you don't have access to stowed/sheathed weapons when it is not your turn.

I never said anything about stowed or sheathed weapons. You can hold two weapons at once, and you also have unarmed strikes. At any moment you could have serveral different reaches.

Nither did i, Read my post again. it dont matter that you second weapon have shorter reach. your reach is 10ft, so they are always in your reach when you have that weapon, so the reaction to move will never trigger.
The key part is "but not in your reach"

You're not answering my question. What is "Your reach"? How is it different from "Your weapon's reach?"

Yes, you can step, with a minor caveat*
"Your Reach" is always dependent on the weapon/unarmed strike you're using.

If you're using a melee weapon or unarmed attack, your target must be within your reach

-Player Core pg. 398

Reach is how far you can physically reach with your body or a weapon. Melee Strikes rely on reach. Your reach is typically 5 feet, but weapons with the reach trait can extend this.

-Player core pg. 426
"Your Reach" is not "the longest reach among weapons and unarmed strikes at your disposal", as that would imply that you can make any attack at that reach, which clearly isn't the case. Each weapon and unarmed strike has its own separate reach, and "your reach" depends on which attack you're using.
Therefore, if you are attacking with a basic Fist unarmed strike, your reach is 5 feet. If you are attacking with a reach weapon, your reach is 10 feet.
*If the enemy is 10 feet away when they trigger the reaction, you can either stay still and strike them with a 10-foot reach weapon, or step and strike with a 5-foot reach weapon.  You CANNOT, however, step and strike with a 10-foot reach weapon, as they were already in your reach, and therefore you were not eligible to step.
